# reported an error when generating MicroROS static link library on STM32F407

Tags: stm32f4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI68L.png)

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/project --env MICROROS_LIBRARY_FOLDER=micro_ros_stm32cubemx_utils/microros_static_library tony/micro-ros-lib-build-humble
```

I am trying to rebuild the static link library and Docker,I hope to resolve this error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).